# Defining the bivariant mapping space functor via the twisted arrow $\infty$-category

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

I have what is surely a very silly question involving the construction of the bivariant mapping space functor $map_C(y,x):C^{op}\times C\to C$ starting from an $\infty$-category C. I’m using Land’s book. This is defined as the straightening of the opposite of the right fibration $Tw(C)\to C\times C^{op}$, where $Tw(C)$ is the twisted arrow category of C. I have two questions about this:

1. It’s asserted (Corollary 4.2.8) that the functor $C\times\{x\}\to C\times C^{op}\to Spaces$, which supposedly classifies the right fibration $Tw(C)_x\to C\times\{x\}$, is equivalent to the one classifying $map_C(-,x)$. First of all, don’t we expect the right fibration $Tw(C)_x\to C\times\{x\}$ to be classified by a functor $C^{op}\times\{x\}\to Spaces$? The proof remarks that there is a Joyal equivalence $C^{/x}\to Tw(C)_x$ over C, so they are equivalent right fibrations. But then both should be classified by a functor $C^{op}\to Spaces$, no?
2. According to Definition 4.2.1, $map_C(-,x)$ is supposedly classified by such a functor $C^{op}\to C$, namely the straightening of the left fibration $(C_{/x})^{op}\to C^{op}$, if I’m not mistaken. But then $y\in C^{op}$ is sent to something equivalent to the fiber $(C_{/x})^{op}_y=(C^{op}_{x/})_y\simeq map_{C^{op}}(x,y)= map_C(y,x)^{op}$, no? But I thought we wanted $y$ to be sent to something equivalent to $map_C(y,x)$.

Everything seems backwards.

Comment: $map_C(-,x)$ cannot be covariant anyway, so you must be right. I think these are typos

Comment: For 1. what you say is correct. As for 2. the functor $K\mapsto K^{op}$, seen from spaces to spaces, is uniquely isomorphic to the identity: it preserves colimits as well as the terminal object. In particular, $map_C(y,x)^{op}=map_C(y,x)$.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you to you both.